# Git diff of single file from two revisions on remote repository

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have updated a file in my working directory and committed it; I've rewritten the entire file so it looks nothing like it did before the commit. I want to pull changes from remote, but the  file I rewrote has been changed by another developer. He did a small change. I want to look at it and put his changes in my rewritten file before I pull and then I can just ignore the conflict between his file and mine when I do pull.

Essentially, I want to look at the diff of a single file between the latest and next-to-latest revisions on the remote repository. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```